# Вывод результата сортировки без изменения порядка элементов в List

Tags: c#, сортировка, list

У меня есть несколько методов которые сортируют List по определенным критериям.

```
    public class StudentRegister
{
    private List<Student> result;
    public List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

    public StudentRegister() { }

    public List<Student> GetList
    {
        get { return studentList; }
    }

    //...методы класса...

    public List<Student> SortByName()  //метод о котором идет речь
    {
        result = studentList;
        result.Sort((b1, b2) => string.Compare(b1.Name, b2.Name));
        return result;
    }
```

В блоке main я делаю сортировку List-а:

```
    class Program
{
    public static void Print(List<Student> list)
    {
        foreach (Student b in list)
            Console.Write(b.ToString());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StudentRegister sr = new StudentRegister();

        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Mary", "Wilkins", (Faculties)2, 215));
        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Ronnie", "Osborn", (Faculties)3, 216));
        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Ivory", "Bloom", (Faculties)4, 319));
        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Abraham", "Thorn", (Faculties)4, 329));
        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Jhon", "Kovalski", (Faculties)1, 115));
        sr.AddStudent(new Student("Minnie", "Mooch", (Faculties)5, 426));

        Print(sr.GetList);
        Console.ReadKey();
        List<Student> sorted = sr.SortByName();
        Console.Clear();
        Print(sorted);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        Print(sr.GetList);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Я бы хотел, чтобы результат сортировки вывелся только на консоль, а сам порядок элементов в List остался прежним, но сортировка меняет порядок элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `List.Sort` сортирует элементы внутри `List`, для того чтобы исходный `List` не был изменен - воспользуйтесь `Linq`, перепишите метод примерно так:

```
public List<Student> SortByName()
{
    return studentList.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
    // или:
    // return studentList.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name).ToList();
}
```

<sub>[Ссылка по теме](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_5.php)</sub>